# Do scheduled paths based on date fields get re-evaluated if the date changes in the field?

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm looking to create scheduled paths for email reminders on a custom object that has a custom field I'll call "Due_Date__c".

If I have a record-triggered flow with a scheduled path for 7 days before the Due_Date__c, but the Due_Date__c has since changed, will it respect the new Due_Date__c value, or the value of Due_Date__c from when the flow was triggered?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you have Date field in `Time source` of the scheduled path and if that field is updated the scheduled action will get rescheduled based on the new date value

Comment: Thanks. Is there a Salesforce doc that validates this behavior?